# XFS CEN not update printer status of ATM

Tags: xfs

I want to get the ATM journal printer status using `WFSGetInfo()` XF API function.
It returns status but it is not updated.

```
HRESULT resultExec= WFSGetInfo( hSer,WFS_INF_PTR_STATUS,NULL,WFS_INDEFINITE_WAIT,&lp);
        printf("\n Printer  Result DeviceAsync===> %d \n", ((LPWFSPTRSTATUS)lp->lpBuffer)->fwDevice);

        switch(((LPWFSPTRSTATUS)lp->lpBuffer)->fwDevice)
        {
        case WFS_PTR_DEVONLINE :
            printf("\n Printer  result WFS_PTR_DEVONLINE : The device is online. \n");
            break;
        case WFS_STAT_DEVHWERROR:
            printf("\n Printer  result WFS_STAT_DEVHWERROR : The device is inoperable due to a hardware error.\n");
            break;
        case WFS_PTR_DEVNODEVICE:
            printf("\n Printer  result WFS_PTR_DEVNODEVICE : There is no device intended to be there; e.g. this type of self service machine does not contain such a device or it is internally not configured.\n");
            break;          
        case WFS_PTR_DEVOFFLINE:
            printf("\n Printer  result WFS_PTR_DEVOFFLINE : The device is offline \n");
            break;          
        case WFS_PTR_DEVPOWEROFF :
            printf("\n Printer  result WFS_PTR_DEVPOWEROFF  : The device is powered off or physically not connected.\n");
            break;                  
        case WFS_PTR_DEVUSERERROR :
            printf("\n Printer  result WFS_PTR_DEVUSERERROR : The device is present but a person is preventing proper device operation.\n");
            break;          
        case WFS_PTR_DEVBUSY :
            printf("\n Printer  result WFS_PTR_DEVBUSY : The device is busy and unable to process an execute command at this time.\n");
            break;          
        case WFS_PTR_DEVFRAUDATTEMPT:
            printf("\n Printer  result WFS_PTR_DEVFRAUDATTEMPT : The device is present but is inoperable because it has detected a fraud attempt.\n");
            break;          
        case WFS_PTR_DEVPOTENTIALFRAUD:
            printf("\n Printer  result WFS_PTR_DEVPOTENTIALFRAUD : The device has detected a potential fraud attempt and is capable of remaining in service. In this case the application should make the decision as to whether to take the device offline.\n");
            break;                   
        }
```

Anyone know why?

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking for. Your code looks good and returns status properly.